# JPA live db schema migration support tools?

Tags: jpa, migration, schema, live

There are quite a few stackoverflow threads regarding JPA db schema migration and assorted tools. However, none seems to even consider service downtimes that can be too long when doing the suggested offline schema migrations for huge databases.

So here is my first thought:

Let's assume I want to refactor one JPA entity into two JPA entities, ie. "Truck" into "Truck" and "Engine" (move the Engine attributes into a separate entity). The migration plan could look like:

- create the two new JPA entities "TruckNew" and "Engine".
- adjust the DAO (or whatever) accessing "Truck", "TruckNew" and "Engine" to:

  - use "Truck" as a fallback
  - run a separate data migration thread that converts entities from "Truck" to "TruckNew" and "Engine", thereby doing the migration in the background without downtime and transparent to the rest of the application(s).
- clean up stuff, rename "TruckNew" to "Truck"

Now the question: are there any support tools for such a task? any JPA provider features that take care of at least part of that work?

Answer (score 0):

I see the idea and it looks possible but wouldn't it be a better approach to clone your database to a migration_db. Migrate your schema using tools/scripts, then test the modifications using unit tests with the new code. Lastly point your environment to configuration to the new installation of the migrated code base with the updated entities.

One downside is that transactions that were not replicated to the cloned database would be lost but this is possible also using just about any transactional database.